# Align form to the left in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a contact page which currently looks like this:
[image: have]

But I want it to look like this:
[image: Want]

How do I accomplish this? I had a look around on the bootstrap website but couldn't really find a good example.
I just started using bootstrap so I'm completely new to it.

My code right now:

```
    <div class="container">
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post"  id="contact_form">
        <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend style="font-weight: bold;">Neem contact op</legend>
        <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
        <h4 style="font-weight: bold; "> Gegevens</h4>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Naam:</span> test<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Woonplaats:</span> test <br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Adres:</span> test <br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Postcode:</span> test <br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Telefoon:</span> test <br>
        </div>  
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Voornaam</label>  
          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
          <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Achternaam</label> 
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
          <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
               <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
          <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Telefoon</label>  
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
          <input name="phone" placeholder="06-12345678" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text area -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Bericht</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Verstuur <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Please don't use tags which are not related to the question.

Comment: If you want them with wide width then try to use col-sm-12 or col-sm-9 rather then col-md-4 as it will took only 25% of screen. Try to read little bit about bs and then beileve me you own will solve your issue :) start here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/index.htm

Comment: @Robbert please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gmbg7z7y/1/  is it ok for you?

Comment: @Leothelion worked thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **HTML Structure** given below.

Some enhancements in **HTML structure** to solve your issue. 
Removed all "**col-md-4**" and added wrapper for each input.

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend style="font-weight: bold;">Neem contact op</legend>
            <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                <h4 style="font-weight: bold; "> Gegevens</h4>
                <span style="font-weight: bold;">Naam:</span> test<br>
                <span style="font-weight: bold;">Woonplaats:</span> test <br>
                <span style="font-weight: bold;">Adres:</span> test <br>
                <span style="font-weight: bold;">Postcode:</span> test <br>
                <span style="font-weight: bold;">Telefoon:</span> test <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Voornaam</label>
                        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Achternaam</label>
                        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
                        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                                <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Telefoon</label>
                        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                                <input name="phone" placeholder="06-12345678" class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text area -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Bericht</label>
                        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Verstuur <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: You fixed my problem better, this didnt mess up the bottom footer and aligned everything correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You can do by removing the class `class-horizontal` from the form tag and change your html accordingly describe below in jsFiddle

**See** :
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfLyLskh/)

Answer (score 0):

According to your image, you need full width then you should not use `col-md-4` as by this your columns will be in 25%(arround) of the space so just do one thing remove them as by default it will be in width which you want..

here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmbg7z7y/2/). I just removed all `col-md-4` and you got your result.

Comment: Sorry but Rahul had a better awnser, your awnser messed with my footer under the form. But thx for your help!

Comment: No worries.. Depends on you.